# Add a timer and update it in c++ linux

Tags: c++, timer, c++14, alarm, beagleboneblack

I am looking to write a function to create an alarm for 10mins and also to add some seconds to it if a condition is met. Not sure where to go from there. I am looking at alarm() but not sure if it terminates the program for the time set in it.

Clarifications: the functions needs to set an alarm/timer for 10 minutes. then if a condition is met, I want to add the alarm some time (ex. adding a minute to alarm if a = b)

any help would be appreciated

Comment: How is the system time "from the internet"? You mean because NTP is running in the background?

Comment: Have you tried printing the current time either side of a `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::hours(1));` ? Was the time difference one hour? Is there a particular reason you're worried that `24` might break where `1` worked correctly?

Comment: yes, since NTP is running in the background. 
The thing is that am not sure if this will check the time once every 24h or will it be visited only once and never again?

Comment: The WDT part is also an important part of the program. any comments on that?

Comment: Depends on how your thread is scheduled. There's nothing in the code shown that would ever stop it repeating. That does mean it depends on an external scheduler (or a dedicated core) and I have no information about that.

Comment: With the watchdog, are you trying to reset an RTC alarm every time the watchdog fires, so the RTC alarm only fires if the WDT has _not_? Or something else? It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: yes, I want the RTC alarm to reset everytime the WDT fires. So that the RTC alarm is always synchronized and doesn't turn the board on by itself.